# Segmentation of the characters of a table

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

How can I segment if the characters are connected with a table ?

I used some filtre to eliminate the table but it destroy the quality of the image which i will use it to recognize the text that contains.

Any help please.

Comment: What have you done? SO is not about ´free' answers or getting work done for you. Ask specific questions to which specific answers can be given.

Comment: Just try to read the first sentence you will find my question

Comment: By specific questions I mean; I've tried to segment the image using algorithm Y or X, but these results are not correct because of specification Z. 
What you ask is insanely broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you need here is a bit of morphology.

I did a few quick tries (using matlab for simplicity, you can do exactly the same thing with OpenCV) and this is what I can get with a couple of morphological operators (closure works fine, but I think that a combination of different operators can yield the best results). Also, the tricky parts will be to find the exact dimension of your structuring elements, I used very small ones (2-3 pixels).

Note that I just tried a couple of operations and the image I post here is just a (very raw) example of what you can do with morphology, but I think it gets the idea.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html) for using it with OpenCV.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do some processing to remove the vertical lines, but perhaps the easiest would be to just learn additional representations of the letters *with* the line.